# Why extensions not active in app electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

#### content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: 'memory'},
  function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

#### background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({data: request.data});
    return true;
  }
});
```

Nothing is displayed.

Comment: What does `extensions not active` mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use `sendResponse`, that is not working currently: check upstream issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16394 .